# Django Rest Framework settings to allow Authentication from Flutter using Authroization key

Tags: python, django, flutter, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am using flutter in the frontend and Django in the backed and am trying to fetch user details, the login is working perfectly fine returning Token key

I keep getting unauthorized or forbidden error and updated the headers several times.

```
  final response = await http.get(
    url,
    headers: {
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
          'Authorization: Bearer ......bla bla ..........',
          //'Bearer ......bla bla bla ...',
    },
  );
```

but I keep getting `{detail: Authentication credentials were not provided.}` and from the Django Rest Framework terminal it is showing: `Forbidden: /api/dj-rest-auth/user/`

Here is the Django settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
.......................
    'rest_framework',
    'users',
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'dj_rest_auth',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'dj_rest_auth.registration',
]


# REST_FRAMEWORK = {
#     'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
#     'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
#
# ]}
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=True
AllowAny =True
```

When I tried to use `'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'`

it returned forbidden when used

`'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',), 'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',)`

returned Unauthorized

here is the views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def aPage(request):
    user:User=User.objects.get(pk=1)
    username=request.POST.get("username")
    email=request.POST.get("email")
    print(email)
    print(username)
    return JsonResponse({"Username":username , "email": email})
```

How can I send authenticate a logged in user using their Token to allow them to get data from api? What am I doing wrong that is returned these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Value of [**`HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpHeaders/authorizationHeader-constant.html) is **"authorization"** becouse of that it's sending invalid headers try like this

```
headers: {
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer xxxxxxxx',
},
```

Comment: I still get `Unauthorized: /api/dj-rest-auth/user/`

Comment: `{detail: Authentication credentials were not provided.}`

Comment: Try to print `request.META` check if it's contain your header.